# Get the value of a twitter bootstrap radio button. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Radio-button from twitter bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons.

In my html in looks like this:

```
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="get_the_value_and_do_something_with_it"
```

I would like to know how to get the value of the button the user checked thanks to Jquery or Javascript.

I saw several question on this topic, but I think it is different with this kind of button, because it looks like they do not accept a "checked" attribute.

Any help would be very welcome

PS: if someone knows how to check by default one of the button, it would also help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

as the tag says it's a `button`, for that, you should do what it suggests, and work with those buttons... here's a simple example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="alignment" value="" />
<div class="btn-group alignment" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

now the jQuery:

```
$(".alignment .btn").click(function() {
    // whenever a button is clicked, set the hidden helper
    $("#alignment").val($(this).text());
});
```

upon submit, you will find the value in the `alignment` hidden field.

Here's a basic example: http://jsbin.com/oveniw/1/

---

a good thing to take attention is that upon click, the element changes and bootstrap appends an `active` class name to the clicked button.

You can always use this to change the `hidden field`, but I would continue to do my example if I wanted to submit the form it self.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, what I wan't to do is to use it in a post function. I guess I can do: $(".alignment .btn").click(function() {
    data = ($(this).text());
    $.post('/url/', {'data': data};  });  Is that right?

Comment: you can simply post the form (witch is probably simpler), the `hidden field` will have the value you need... as I'm in .NET, a `Request["alignment"]` will have the button that was pressed if you just submit as `<input type="submit" value="Submit form" />` or even `$("form").submit();`

Comment: I tried but I didn't find how to do what I wanted to do. I posted a more detailed question about my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351586/jquery-post-function-with-radio-button-django). And thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 10):

You can "check" a button by setting its class to ´active´:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn active">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

To get a value, you should have a "value" data, such as:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" id="my_radiogroup">
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="0">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn active" data-value="1">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-value="2">Right</button>
</div>
```

This way, you may get the value via:

```
$("#my_radiogroup .active").data("value");
>>> 1
(but may, of course, be undefined if no button is checked)
```

But keep in mind that the value won't be posted in your form, unless you have a `<input type=hidden>` to actually store the selected data.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to make this complicated.

Say you have a button group, for selecting whether something is active or inactive...like so...

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="productStatus btn btn-success" value="1">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="productStatus btn btn-danger" value="0">No</button>
</div>
```

When you run a function or anything to gather your selected button, you would run this command...which would get you the value of your selected radio button.  When you click on a button, or more to the point, when it's "checked", it's given the class of "active" like in previous answers.  That's all you really need to look for.  With this little snippet below.

```
var active = $('.productStatus[class*="active"]').val();
alert(active);
```

Basically it's using a wildcard selector looking for this "productStatus" button class, and then returning the value of the button that has the "active" class.

Comment: i think using ```$('.productStatus.active')``` would be a lot neater.

Answer (score 2):

I use this hook when a number of Bootstrap radio buttons more than one

```
$('div[data-toggle="buttons-radio"] .btn').click(function(){
    $('input[name="' + $(this).parent().attr('id') + '"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

And in HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="rental" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="0">Sale</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="1">Rent</button>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="rental" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected as follows:

```
$('.btn-group button.btn.active')
```

To, set a button active

```
$(selector).addClass('active')
```

For example, if you want set the first button active:

```
$('.btn-group button.btn:eq(0)').addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of radio button on submission of form in a function or any click event of submit button

```
alert($('.btn-group > .btn.active').attr("value"));
```