# jQuery post function with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my Django app, I would like to use Twitter bootstrap radio buttons. Then I would like to post the value of those buttons in order to create an object.

Here is my buttons:

```
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team2</button>
  </div>


  <div class="span6 btn-group ib" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">relaxed</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">strict</button>
  </div>



  <input type="submit" value="create your match">
```

I would like to get the information from those radio button and create an object match with it in a view:

```
   def test(request):
       user=request.user
       if request.method == 'POST':
       style = request.POST['style']
       supporting = request.POST['supporting']
       match = Match.objects.create(user=user, style=style, supporting=supporting)
     return HttpResponse(test)
```

The thing is that I don't know JavaScript well, so I didn't find how to get the value from the button.

Then, I think I have to use:

```
 $.post('/sportdub/points_dub/', {'style': style , 'supporting': supporting});
```

But how can I do so that style and supporting correspond to the value of the buttons, and then to post it only when the user clicks on the button?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: so... why don't you use my snippet from the other answer? what was wrong? All you have to do is `alignment = request.POST['alignment']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your most recent comment, I think you should try using the input radio buttons provided in HTML.  It is very easy to do button groupings, make labels for the inputs, and retrieve which one has been clicked.

Altering your HTML slightly to look like this (the for attribute of the label allows the user to be able to click the label and select the radio button instead of clicking on the button directly):

```
  <div>
    <input id="team1" type="radio" name="supporting" value="Team1" /><label for="team1">Team 1</label>
    <input id="team2" type="radio" name="supporting" value="Team2" /><label for="team2">Team 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="relaxed" type="radio" name="style" value="relaxed" /><label for="relaxed">Relaxed</label>
    <input id="strict" type="radio" name="style" value="strict" /><label for="strict">Strict</label>
  </div>
```

I can get which selections have been made using this:

```
$('input[name="supporting"]').filter(':checked').val();
$('input[name="style"]').filter(':checked').val();
```

If you still wish to use buttons, class `active` is added to a radio button when clicked.  To get the button text, try:

```
$('button[name="supporing"]').filter('.active').text();
$('button[name="style"]').filter('.active').text();
```

To put this value into a hidden input, do the following:

```
$('#hiddenInput1').val($('button[name="supporting"]').filter('.active').text());
$('#hiddenInput2').val($('button[name="style"]').filter('.active').text());
```

Comment: Ok, but I have two different values to get. How can I get them both, and then pass them into my post function only when the user clicks on the submit button?

Comment: @JulietteDupuis I have updated my answer to show you how to get the text of only the buttons with a name of style.  Are you only trying to get the text of the buttons that have a name of style?  Or are you trying to find which buttons the user has clicked on?

Comment: thank you for your help. I try to find wich button the user has clicked on for both "style" and "supporting". Then pass those informations into a post function in order to use it in my view test.

Comment: @JulietteDupuis I think I understand now.  Please look at my revised comment.  This should allow you to find which selections have been made.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I really try to use those twitter bootstrap buttons. Since I'm developing with django, I could do that without javascript if I use html radio button. But thank you for your help.

Comment: @JulietteDupuis I have added the ability to use buttons to my answer.  The active class is added when the button is clicked.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. could you just show me how I can put this value into an hidden input? like $(.test).$('button[name="supporing"]').filter('.active').text();  and then I render it with: <input type="hidden" class="test"/> ?

Comment: @JulietteDupuis Sorry for the late response, but I have added your request to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

taking my [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13348783/28004), let's use your own code... in your HTML you have something like:

```
<form action="/sportdub/points_dub/" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="span6 btn-group ib" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">relaxed</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">strict</button>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="create your match" />

</form>
```

and you just have to add one hidden field per block, in your case, add 2. Your form would then match:

```
<form action="/page" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

  <input type="hidden" id="supporting_team" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="supporting_type" value="" />

  <div class="btn-group supporting_team" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="supporting">Team2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="span6 btn-group ib supporting_type" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">relaxed</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" name="style">strict</button>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="create your match" />

</form>
```

add a jQuery helper that will set the values of those hidden fields upon buttons click:

```
// whenever a button is clicked, set the hidden helper
$(".supporting_team .btn").click(function() {
    $("#supporting_type").val($(this).text());
}); 
$(".supporting_type .btn").click(function() {
    $("#supporting_team").val($(this).text());
});
```

when you click the `create your match` the entire form will be posted to the page set as the `action` attribute of the form, you have to do nothing more...

If you want to submit it manually by invoking `post` in javascript you need to remember to prevent the form to be submitted again as that's the `input type="submit"` element task, you can invoke your post and serializing the entire form data, instead one by one as in your example...

like:

```
// when the form is submited...
$("form").submit(function() {

   // submit it using `post`
   $.post('/sportdub/points_dub/', $("form").serialize()); 

   // prevent the form to actually follow it's own action
   return false; 

});
```

in your dynamic code, you will have those variables as:

```
supportingTeam = request.POST['supporting_team']
supportingType = request.POST['supporting_type']
```

and this, will be valid, no matter if you have the manually form submit script or not...

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to do that, and then I figured that it would be easier for me to use "data-value" of the buttons to create my object with the posted data. So I try to use $("#id_of_radiogroup .active").data("value");  Now, I would like to pass this value inside my hidden inputs, without using the (click.()), because I wan't to check by default the buttons and I don't wan't to allow empty choices. So I try to find out how to pass the data-value of the buttons into the hidden input. Anyway, thank you very much for your answers, you really helped me a lot.