# How to use bootstrap toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a toggle buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical  btn-block no-padding" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block full-width">button1</button>
    <button type="button"   onclick="admLayer();" class="btn btn-block full-width">button2</button>
</div>
```

When i press button2 i call admLayer() function. All works fine but like simple button. How to send to function when button pressed or unpressed?

**UPDATE**

I try use http://www.larentis.eu/bootstrap_toggle_buttons/ :

```
        <script>
        $('#btn-group btn-group-vertical  btn-block no-padding').toggleButtons({
            onChange: function ($el, status, e) {
            console.log($el, status, e);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

But its not work.
Whats can be wrong?

Comment: use different styles for pressed and unpressed

Comment: @Roar; Can you give an example?

Comment: post what u have tryed to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348672/get-the-value-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-radio-button-jquery. Its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakenly selecting the div on the basis of Id, If you want to select the div, you should do something like this :-

```
<script>
    $(".btn-group").toggleButtons({
        onChange: function ($el, status, e) {
        console.log($el, status, e);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Classes are selected with Dot('.') and ids are selected with Hash('#').

Thanks