# How to get radio button group values in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following code of bootstrap for my radio buttons inside a form

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
   <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary active">Present</button>
   <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary">Absent</button>
   <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary">Leave</button>
</div>
```

You can find radio example by visiting http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

I am using this for employees attendance, so there are multiple records of employees and there will be a array. 
I have tried question [Get the value of a twitter bootstrap radio button. JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348672/get-the-value-of-a-twitter-bootstrap-radio-button-jquery)
but this returns me only last selected value.

How can I solve this??

Note: I have also tried input tag instead of button but that effect styling

Comment: you can use :

  $('.btn-group').find('button').each(function(i){
      var val = $(this).val();
  });

Comment: I need array of data with name att on form submit

Comment: you can create a hidden field and store the array of radio button values there, using the code I commented on earlier and pushing the values of the radio buttons into an array. i.e :

<input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="array(1,0,0)"> so that when you send the array, it will be included in $_POST[];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solve the question by using

```
  <div id ="attend1" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
       <input type='hidden' name="attendy[]" value='default value'>
       <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary active">Present</button>
       <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary">Absent</button>
       <button type="button" name="att" class="btn btn-primary">Leave</button>
    </div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   $('.btn').click(function() {
      var parent = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
      $(parent).find('input').val($(this).text());
   });
 });
```

Thanks alot everyone

Comment: Awesome - I had to search for a while to get this.  I will add: for ppl who need this value at the server level, you can read the value of control "attendy" on postback.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` attribute to `.btn-group` and use this:

```
var activebtnvalue = $("#btngroup").find("button.active").prop('value');
```

Add a `value` attribute to each button as well.

Comment: I need array on form post

Comment: Change `activebtnvalue` to `myarr['btngroup']` then.