# How to use Bootstrap radio buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap 2.3.2` and I can't seem to get `radio buttons` to work. I'm using the code from Bootstrap's website:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

What do I need to do from here? With this I get 3 buttons, but clicking them doesn't change them to active and they don't look like they've been clicked.

EDIT:

If I initialize the buttons in JS like so:

`$('.btn-group').button();`

This markup is generated for the group:

```
<div class="btn-group ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all 
            ui-button-text-only" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" 
            role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Compared to this on the bootstrap website:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Right</button>
</div>
```

Not sure why it's working different here.

Comment: Have you included the required javascript files to support the functionality?

Comment: @StevenV Yes, I included boostrap.js and it looks to have all JS for all components. Do I need to initialize them in JS though? Because right now all I have is whats above.

Comment: Yes. You need to use `$('.btn-group').button()` to start the functionality.

Comment: look at this question once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031608/how-to-get-radio-button-group-values-in-bootstrap?rq=1

Comment: You do not have to initialise the button group. See zessx answer below and try removing the initialisation script from his example and re-run the fiddle. You will see that the required bootstrap includes handle this based upon the classes only.

Answer (score 7):

Looking in [Bootstrap 2.3.2 doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons) (see Usage section), you need to initialize your buttons :

```
$('.btn-group').button();
```

[Working example based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7JfMp/)

Comment: This is not required. Try removing this from your fiddle and you will find it is all handled by the css and includes. I believe the OP may not have included some files correctly as the poster below mentions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
</label>
</div>
```

Make sure to incluse the right class names and attach the stylesheet in the header